# Hdfs: name node block locations

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Does name node stores block locations persistently? 
As per my understanding, namenode stores namenode space image and edit log stores permanently. 
Please clarify?

Answer (score 3):

The information about the location of blocks is not persisted by NN. NN builds it dynamically with the help of `block reports` sent by DNs . NN metadata includes entire file system namespace, including the mapping of blocks to files and file system properties. All this information is stored permanently in the `fsimage` file. You can find this file at the location specified by `dfs.name.dir` in your `hdfs-site.xml` file.

Comment: I am wrong, in the above statement.
Name node does not store bolck locations persistently.
It will store the filesystem tree and meta data of files and directories in the tree persistently: in form of two files : namenode space image and edit log.

Comment: I have updated the answer in order to make it more clear.